# How to check XSLT errors

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, detection

I have `XSLT` and `XMl` files to treat.

I need to know how to detect the following errors in large XSLT files (listed by the order of priority):

1. Xpath errors
2. Tag errors
3. Syntax errors

Is there a tool that can do all these on Windows plaform?

Comment: Emacs' `nxml` mode does most of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) ? of course, it depends of the size of your xml/xsl.

```
xsltproc --noout input.xsl input.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Any XSLT processor will do this. Saxon's diagnostics are probably better than most, though I say it myself. An IDE such as Oxygen or Stylus Studio is useful (both have Saxon under the hood), because the error messages will take you straight to the offending code. You don't say whether you want XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use altova xml spy. Its a shareware not a freeware. However, you can use this as a trial version.